# how to convert the 24 hr format into 12 hour with meridiem format in symfony

Tags: symfony1

Good day. I'm new to symfony and I'm using symfony doctrine 1.4. my question is how to convert the 24 hour format into a 12 hour format in symfony? here some code(based on my project):

```
 **project\reservation\config\doctrine\schema.yml**
 startime: { type: time, notnull: true }
    endtime:  { type: time, notnull: true }
```

as you can see here in my schema.yml format code. I set my startime  and endtime into time data type so I can use for time checking on my project. and also I set this code to remove seconds and I set the range the hours from 1 to 12 (no meridiem)

```
 **project\reservation\lib\form\doctrine\reservationApplicationForm.class.php**

        $hour = range(1, 12);
          $this->widgetSchema['startime'] = new sfWidgetFormTime(array(
              'with_seconds' => false,
              'hours' => array_combine($hour, $hour),
              'format_without_seconds' => '%hour% : %minute%' 

            ));

          $this->widgetSchema['endtime'] = new sfWidgetFormTime(array(
              'with_seconds' => false,
              'hours' => array_combine($hour, $hour),
              'format_without_seconds' => '%hour% : %minute%' 
            ));
```

but when I press the submit button to display, I get this format, (assume I type 7:00 in startime and 5:00 in endtime i get this 7:00:00 and 5:00:00 on my display)

well i was expecting that my output should be 7:00 and 5:00 but no meridiem.

Can anyone help me to convert the 24hr format in 12 hour with a meridiem format(am/pm). I was expecting to display this format H:i (am/pm).

thanks

P.S

Sorry for a bad english I'm a filipino

Answer (score 0):

You should install the `sfFormtasticPlugin`, see: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormtasticPlugin

In this plugin you find this class handling 12 hour format: http://svn.symfony-project.com/plugins/sfFormtasticPlugin/trunk/lib/widget/sfWidgetasticFormTime.class.php

PS: My trip to camiguin was awesome! :)

Comment: Thank for your reply ^^, but I got another problem, I download the plugin and placed it on the plugin directory. but when I'm gonna install it on the command prompt I got this error, `No release available in sfFormtasticPlugin`, help!! thx